# Converting a jQuery setInterval timing into a recursive setTimeout timing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a code snippet for a Queue Management System here that dynamically fetch data from the database based from the number of window allowed to be shown on the screen.

```
    var elementArray;

    function fetchPayment() {
        elementArray = new Array();
        $('.win_id').each(function() {
            // here's the moneyshot
            elementArray.push(this);
        });
        doAjax(0);
    }

    function doAjax(param) {
        if (typeof elementArray[param] === 'undefined') {
            var win_id = 0;
        } else {
            var win_id = elementArray[param].value;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            //                async: false,
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>queue/getCurrentTransaction/" + win_id,
            success: function(data) {
                param++;
                if (param <= elementArray.length) {
                    $('.names-' + win_id).empty();
                    $('.names-' + win_id).append("<div class='pname'>" + data.customer_name + '<li>' + data.ref_code + '</li></div>');
                    doAjax(param);

                } else {
                    console.log("!");
                }

            },
            error: function(data) {
                param++;
                $('.names-' + win_id).empty();
                $('.names-' + win_id).append("<div class='pname'><li></li></div>");
                doAjax(param);
            }
        });
    }
```

This works, however, it's too CPU intensive and it is admittedly a bad approach, I refactored my other functions to make them something like this:

```
    (function fetchNewServiceConnection() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>queue/getCurrentTransaction/" + 100,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.c_name').empty();
                    $('.c_name').append(data.customer_name + '<li>' + data.ref_code + '</li>');
                    fetchNewServiceConnection()
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $('.c_name').empty();
                    $('.c_name').append('<li></li>');
                    fetchNewServiceConnection()
                }
            });
        }, 500);
    })();
```

This works much much faster. The problem is the code above, how do I convert it to be like the code snippet below?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It appears that you're trying to offset the loading of the ajax calls (server side processing) for each available element/payment on the page.

Comment: Here's what I want to do:
Every 2 seconds, I need to fetch data from the database for each element/payment window.

Comment: Does it matter if the previous request has completed or can it happen synchronously?

Comment: synchronously, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your

```
function doAjax(param) {

    if (typeof elementArray[param] === 'undefined') {
        var win_id = 0;
    } else {
        var win_id = elementArray[param].value;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    // etc....
        
}
```

you have `doAjax(param);` in two places, one for `success:` and one for `error:`

---

> replace **`doAjax(param);`** in both places with:
>
> **`setTimeout(doAjax.bind(null, param), 500);`**

---

***Note:***
I'm not sure, but it looks like you're trying to do ***`"real time data"`***, so my suggestion is to look at ***`WebSockets`*** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), host your own, or, eventually, providers like Pusher.com (https://pusher.com/)